# Can't connect python with titan db

Tags: titan, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

Following the steps to configure the titan srever

```
bin/titan.sh

Forking Cassandra...
Running `nodetool statusthrift`... OK (returned exit status 0 and printed string "running").
Forking Elasticsearch...
Connecting to Elasticsearch (127.0.0.1:9300)... OK (connected to 127.0.0.1:9300).
Forking Gremlin-Server...
Connecting to Gremlin-Server (127.0.0.1:8182)... OK (connected to 127.0.0.1:8182).
Run gremlin.sh to connect.
```

The server started perfectly but when i am connecting with python and then run the script the error which i got mentioned below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin-12/Documents/bitbucket/ecodrone/ecodrone/GremlinConnector.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = (execute_query("""g.V()"""))
  File "/home/admin-12/Documents/bitbucket/ecodrone/ecodrone/GremlinConnector.py", line 22, in execute_query
    results = future_results.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 81, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 77, in _receive
    self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 71, in data_received
    result_set = results_dict[request_id]
KeyError: None
```

versioning i am using
titan - 1.0.0
gremlin-python - 3.3.2
apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan supports some an extremely old version of TinkerPop and I'm sure you'll find some incompatibility there if you try to use gremlin-python 3.3.2. As Titan is no longer supported, I suggest you upgrade to [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org/), a more current and maintained version of Titan.

Comment: I tried to work on JanusGraph but I did not get the success to connect with gremlin-python  3.3.2. so I tried with lower version something like 3.2.3 and it works perfectly I did not understand what the problem would be

Comment: I assume you were using JanusGraph 0.2 which is bound to TinkerPop 3.2.7. https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/0.2/pom.xml#L68 so for best results you should use gremlin-python 3.2.7. That said, 3.2.8 should also work.